# How to avoid code repeating on Git repository branches

Tags: android, git, software-design

I am working on Android project with 4 developers.

and the **Client** order the following :

1. New design for the app (4 developers)
2. Keep updates and fixes till new design ready (1 developer)

My issue is :

How to apply the above on Git repository (branches)

Shall I create a new branch for re-design and another one for update and fixes ? and what is the best usage to avoid code moving and repeating ?

some updates and fixes may affect java classes that under design changing.

Advice, please. 
Very thanks

Comment: so the logic will stay almost the same? only the UI has redesign?

Comment: @user1506104 ,
the UI will change (without showing)
and some updates and fixes will be applied on the old UI (for Google play updates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Git, this can be done easily via Basic Branching and Merging workflow. 
Your team should know how to apply Git operations like branch switching, merging and how to solve branches conflicts.
A full article about this can be found in [Git documentation here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)
is covers a case similar to yours.